# package node with pkg ERR_INSPECTOR_NOT_AVAILABLE at run time

Tags: node.js, zeit-pkg

I am playing with pkg to package a command line example I got from a blog post.  The executable created fine but when I try to run the executable, I am getting the following error:

```
pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:1244
      throw error;
      ^

Error [ERR_INSPECTOR_NOT_AVAILABLE]: Inspector is not available
    at inspector.js:24:9
    at NativeModule.compileForInternalLoader (internal/bootstrap/loaders.js:276:7)
    at NativeModule.compileForPublicLoader (internal/bootstrap/loaders.js:218:10)
    at loadNativeModule (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:9)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:906:15)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1087:19)
    at Module.require (pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:1225:31)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:73:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/snapshot/ginit/lib/repo.js:11:17)
    at Module._compile (pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:1320:22) {
  code: 'ERR_INSPECTOR_NOT_AVAILABLE'
}
```

I put the package on github and here is the link: [Link to github](https://github.com/billtlee/ginit)

Any help is greatly apprecited on how to get this to work.

Comment: Did you get it to work by any chance? Facing the same problem at the moment.

Comment: No, gave up and used GO to write the module.

Answer (score 0):

This Error comes up when we try to Start the executable in `DEBUG` mode.

Since `pkg` doesn't allow *Inspecting* the run-time code of the executable this error **Inspector is not available** shows up.

I was trying to `spawn` the executable from another program (which was running in `DEBUG` mode) and it caused the same issue.
But when I started the program in *normal* mode, it worked like a charm

Comment: Hi, facing the same problem. You said "when I started the program in normal mode, it worked like a charm". How do you invoke this "normal" mode exactly (example?). $NODE_OPTIONS is empty in my environment so no "debug" is set. I would really appreciate step-by-step instructions. Thanks!

Comment: By 'normal' mode, I meant 'not debug' mode. Are you sure you are running the program in 'non-debug' mode?